# jQuery slider to change HTML table content in div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a 3D array of values in HTML tables. I want to be able to switch between HTML tables in a `<div>` element.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56B5p/)**

there will be 15 "layers" of HTML tables. The one slider I have

```
vSlider2
```

This is the short vertical slider on the right which controls which layer will be displayed. I have an array with the table id's in it which would be linked to the html for each table.

This is the lines of code I don't think are working:

```
var j =$('#amount3').val(); //this is what doesn't work but if I set j=1 it does

$('#tab').html(tab[j]);
```

In the fiddle, if I put `var j=1;` it works fine.

I must be missing something here. I was wondering if I may have set it up wrong to allow the page to update automatically? I thought that being in the ready function I'd be OK with that.

Thanks for any assistance you can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't that it was an int or string, it was that the action of loading the html was outside the slider function.  When I added the change to the div in the slider function the html updated:

http://jsfiddle.net/56B5p/1/

```
function VcreateSlider2(slider, boundTextField) {
slider.slider({
  orientation: "vertical",
  range: "max",
  min: 1,
  max: 15,
  value: 15,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    boundTextField.val(16- ui.value );
      $('#tab').html(tab[15-ui.value]);

$('tr > td').each(function(index) {
    var scale = [['bad',-99],['vPoor', 10], ['poor', 20], ['avg', 40], ['good', 60], ['vGood', 80]];
    var score = $(this).text();
    for (var i = 0; i < scale.length; i++) {
        if (score <= scale[i][1]) {
            $(this).addClass(scale[i][0]);
        }
    }
});
  }
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're trying to get the value as an `Integer`. It happens that the value you're getting comes as a `String`.

Maybe this link will be helpfull:

[JavaScript Documentation - parseInt() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Good luck :)

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it still didn't change the html when the slider was activated.